# Including sub project (SocketRocket) is looking for CFNetwork in wrong place

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, shared-libraries

I am trying to include [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) in my project. But it is not finding the CFNetwork.framework.

More specifically it is looking for it in the wrong place. Here is the error:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
  Referenced from: /Volumes/MacintoshHD/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KeyServer-chcnhqzvlfxnmzdqlyfdmokatrfw/Build/Products/Debug/SocketRocket.framework/Versions/A/SocketRocket
  Reason: image not found`

It is looking for CFNetwork here:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork`

It should afaik be looking for it within the SocketRocket.framework. E.g. here:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreService.framework/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork`

Any ideas? I must be missing a flag or something. I am on OSX 10.7.

Comment: did you have any luck on this?

Comment: Sorry – so long ago I have forgotten.